# Paying bill in Switzerland

Tags: switzerland

I am new to Switzerland (Suisse Romande, French speaking part) but I do hold a Swiss citizenship so I have to fill the same paper as all Swiss citizens.

Anyway I have to pay my health insurance (prime d'assurance maladie) but I have no idea how to do it, there are a few choices, I chose "bulletin de versement" thinking it would be easy but it seems that I cannot pay using only the 2 series of number they gave me.

I contacted the insurance saying I would like to pay by BVR (at La poste) or by payment card, they told me I can fill an empty BVR with the number they gave me with the bulletin de versement.

Anyone knows how to do it ? In this case can I pay with my card ? (last time I paid to La poste I could only pay in cash...)

Or better, anyone knows how I have to proceed to make a bank transfer or pay with a payment card ?

(keep in mind that the way to pay a bill is very different in Switzerland than in the rest of Europe so any answer from other European countries experience might no work here)

Comment: @jcaron I did not know that there was an expatriates SE, anyway I do only hold a French bank account in CHF, I do not think they offer this possibilty, I will contact them just to be sure.

Comment: You will most definitely need a Swiss bank account if you live in Switzerland. Nearly everything is paid using the "bulletins", and those only work using Swiss bank accounts if you want to use e-banking. As stated in the answer below, you could also just go to the post office with the bulletin and pay in cash. Some providers will allow bank transfers, in which case you need to ask for BIC + IBAN, and they will need a reference to be sent with the payment. Note that Switzerland is part of SEPA but not of the EU (and the payment is in CHF), so fees for bank transfers from FR will be much higher.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try to pay this one in cash as the due date is soon and will open a Swiss bank account !

Comment: "keep in mind that the way to pay a bill is very different in Switzerland than in the rest of Europe so any answer from other European countries experience might no work here" My experience of paying bills in the UK and Germany didn't seem so different (but in all cases I have had a local bank account, and used internet banking).

Comment: @MartinBonner I have lived mostly in France (and a bit in Germany) and I have never seen this system of payment with La poste there, as well as in European countries (that have €) usually you can provide the companies that offers you a service (internet provider, insurance etc) an IBAN and they take directly the money from your account. It does not seem to be the case in Switzerland (or at least it's much less common).

Comment: I am voting to close this since the OP  is asking about how to do stuff in Switzerland as a Swiss citizen. Definitely nothing to do with expats!

Comment: @stbr - I'm in Zürich.  My health insurance takes the money direct from my bank account.  It's called a "Lastschriftmandat" in German - no idea what the French equivalent is.

Comment: @ScottEarle I said that I'm a Swiss citizen but the question is about paying a bill, thing that any expat has to do ! Expats also have to pay health insurance, internet bills and so on. (perhaps the first sentence of my question is confusing and pretty much useless)

Comment: @MartinBonner Do you need a Swiss account to do that ?

Comment: @stbr Yes, of course.  But you need a Swiss account to be paid too.

Comment: @MartinBonner I have an account in CHF from a French bank and I get my salary here without any trouble, but when it comes with paying bills that's where the problems appear.

Comment: But you’re not an expat. This site is not for questions about how regular people do stuff in their own country, it’s for expats to ask about how to do stuff *as an expat*. So your question is by definition off-topic

Comment: @ScottEarle Call it whatever you want but when you move to another country for the first time of your life by definition you are not an expat but in fact you are one as you have to find out how things work, and that's the point of this site if I am right. I'm pretty sure that if I hadn't stated that I am a citizen you would not have wrote it, so should I remove my first sentence to make it more clear ?

Comment: I still contend that “finding out how things work” is very different as a citizen of the country than for foreigners. Where I live, if I asked how to file taxes, apply for a job, open a bank account ... none of the information would apply to me, because foreigners are treated differently to locals literally everywhere. That is life as an expat. Locals here don’t have to report their whereabouts every 90 days, they have different house registration books, don’t need a work permit - everything is different. Life as an expat is very different to life as a local. In most places in the world.

Comment: You are assessing that YOUR situation is the typical expat one. Seems that you forgot that you moved from UK to Asia where culture is A LOT different ! You can be an expat from France to Germany and you'll still have some differences that would lead to relevent questions. And I am sorry but I have to disagree, in Europe NOT everything is different as an expat, paying the bill (exception for income taxes) is only slightly different, if I was not a citizen there would be NO difference in paying my internet, health insurance, water / electricity and rent bill (which is the point of my question).

Comment: I agree that this is an expat question as stbr has moved to Switzerland for the first time in his life. It deals with the cultural shock of moving to a country you never lived in before and understanding how a person without a local bank account can bootstrap their life "abroad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your situation exactly (are you a swiss expatriate coming back to the country but not speaking the language ?), but let's say this doesn't really matter.

The easiest way, accessible to anyone, is to go to any post office, and pay the bill in cash. They'll do the paperwork for you.

A faster way is to use e-banking and this is what most people do - they pay the bill directly on the internet at their banks website, so that they don't need to use cash nor to queue at the post office. However this requires a bank account and an internet access.

Comment: I do speak the language and I am moving to Switzerland for the first time, what is the difference between bulletin de versement and e-banking as in my mind the first one can also be paid online. I do have a french bank account in CHF but I am not sure wether it is possible to pay the bill with such.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien ton problème mais le bulletin de versement c'est le papier orange; l'e-banking c'est un service offert par la banque. Dans tout les cas les bulletins de versement sont payables à la poste si tu as l'argent en cash. Je ne sais pas si c'est possible de payer depuis un compte français, mais dans ce cas peut être faut-il utiliser l'IBAN et un compte international.

Comment: J'ai choisis le payement par bulletin de versement sur le site de mon assureur mais je n'ai reçu qu'une facture PDF disponible sur leur portail (sans papier orange donc) avec 2 séries de chiffres (une correspondante au compte si je ne me trompe pas) avec lesquelles je suis censé pouvoir régler ma facture de prime. Peut-être qu'ils se sont trompés et qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un bulletin de versement ?

Comment: Je vois - c'est en fait un BVR mais avec seulement les inscriptions et sans le canevas en orange, qui est toujours le même. Il existe à la poste des bulletins vides qu'on peut remplir soi-même, donc je pense que c'est ce que tu es censé faire. Bonne chance en tout cas...

Comment: Merci pour la réponse, ma banque en France possède un siège à Bâle et est donc habilitée à proposer des comptes en CHF (ce que j'ai fais) mais apparemment seul les comptes de banques Suisses permettent de profiter du paiement par e-banking. Je vais régler ma première facture de prime à La poste via un bulletin vide comme vous me l'avez suggéré (j'aurai préféré éviter cette solution étant donné qu'il s'agit du paiement d'une prime sur plusieurs mois, plus de 1000.- donc) car le délai me semble un peu court pour ouvrir un compte. Ensuite je me renseignerai pour ouvrir un compte

Comment: chez une banque Suisse*. D'ailleurs si vous avez des suggestions je serai heureux de les écouter, je cherche une banque avec des frais limités (peu importe si celle-ci offre peu de service puisque je voudrais conserver mon compte en €). Le compte en CHF me servant uniquement à recevoir mon salaire, payer mes factures et les dépenses uniquement en francs.

Comment: May I ask that you add a summary of this comments in English for everyone to understand?

Comment: @stbr it is usually recommended to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer in stack exchange.

Comment: To keep it short, you can usually pay your bills in Switzerland at La Poste in cash using a BVR (which is usually an orange paper, but not mendatory, in my case I can use bank account number and fill an empty BVR). Otherwise to use online payment it's required to have a Swiss account (I had a french account in CHF but seems that it does not allow me to pay my bills online with it).